# Give one list of lists to a function with multiple parameters

Tags: list-manipulation

I am a huge beginner in mathematica.

My question is the following :

I need to compute :

```
SixJSymbol[{j1, j2, j3}, {j4, j5, j6}]
```

I would like to create a list like that :

```
List[{j1, j2, j3}, {j4, j5, j6}]
```

And to directly give it to the SixJSymbol function.

How to do it ?

I read topic advised when I wrote this message but I find the answers a little too hard (I just begin with mathematica : I can create lists, functions, plots but that is basically all that I can do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your list:

```
lst = {{j1, j2, j3}, {j4, j5, j6}};
```

Try this

```
SixJSymbol @@ lst

(*  SixJSymbol[{j1, j2, j3}, {j4, j5, j6}]  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Hi, thanks for always providing such short and concise answers. I was wondering if you could kindly help me with this problem: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146596/defining-general-functions-and-functionals-in-mathematica I am very new to Mathematica and am rather lost. Thanks in any case.